# Application of Bruhat decomposition in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: group-theory

Consider the General Linear group $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ over the field of order $p$,  $B$ denote the subgroup consisting of upper triangular matrices, and $W$ denotes the subgroup consisting of matrices obtained by permuting columns of the $n\times n$ identity matrix (so $W\cong S_n$).

**Bruhat decomposition:** any element of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ can be written as $bwb'$ ($b,b'\in B$, $w\in W$).

As an application of this decomposition, one can *easily* prove the following: let $U$ denote the subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$, consisting of upper triangular matrices whose each diagonal entry is $1$. Then *the only elements of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$ which normalize the subgroup $U$ are the upper triangular matrices.*

To prove this, if an element $bwb'$ normalizes $U$, then since $b,b'$ obviously normalize $U$, it follows that the permutation matrix $w$ should normalize $U$, and the only such matrix is the identity.

**Question** What are the other applications of Bruhat decomposition in the theory of the group $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Comment: This decomposition, together with its generalization to groups with a $(B,N)$-pair, plays a central role in the devlopment of the basic properties of groups of Lie type, such as parabolic subgroups, formulae for the orders of the finite groups, simplicity proofs, th Steinberg presentations, etc.